# Why does ch_evalraw() evaluate to my message instead of the response?

Tags: job-control

I am trying to learn about jobs and channels on Vim (on Windows), and I am using the following sequence as an example:

```
let job = job_start("cmd")
let channel = job_getchannel(job)
let response = ch_evalraw(channel, "dir\n")
```

Here `echo response` yields `dir` instead of what I expect, the first line of output from dir (`Volume in drive C is OS`).  Why is this the case, and how can I modify this to get what I expect?

Comment: Does it stop returning `"dir"` itself if you run `"cmd /k"` instead? I think what you're seeing is `cmd`'s "echo", which I believe is somewhat common in DOS/Windows (at least I recall having to start my `.BAT` files with `@echo off` back in the day...) See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd

Comment: I still get ``dir`` when I run ``cmd /k`` instead.  I also get the same result if I replace cmd.exe with powershell.exe, and ``dir`` with ``ls``

Comment: On the other hand, if I replace cmd.exe with bash.exe that comes with Git on Windows , and ``dir`` with ``ls``, then I get the first line of output of ``ls``

Comment: Ah, sorry... I meant `cmd /q` (for quiet.) I think it's normal that you only get the first line of output... I'm not super familiar with jobs and channels, but that's what I'm getting too. If you just want to run an external command and get the output, using `systemlist()` is much more straightforward!

Comment: ``cmd /q`` works -- I get ``Volume in drive C is OS`` instead of ``dir``

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're seeing the command you just ran coming back in the channel is because Windows' `cmd.exe` will by default run with “echo” on, which means it will print back the command to be executed before executing it and sending back the output produced by it.

You can use `job_start("cmd /q")` to have it disable “echo” at startup, which should solve the problem and have your read from the channel return the first line produced by the `dir` command. See [documentation for `cmd.exe`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd) at Microsoft's website.

Another alternative is using, for example, `bash.exe` from a distribution such as Git Bash, which will not produce the “echo” you've seen with `cmd`.

---

Note that a read from the channel will only produce the first line of output from `dir` and further channel reads don't seem to send the next lines of output from that command. I haven't really used Vim jobs and channels extensively, so I'm not really sure what the issue there is. You might want to ask a separate question about that if you'd like to explore that further...

If all you want is to capture the output of an external command, a much easier approach is to use the `system()` or `systemlist()` functions, which will take care of all the details for you and simply return a string or list. For example, to put the output of `dir` under the cursor in the current buffer, all you need is:

```
:put =systemlist('dir')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and I apologize for my slow interaction.  I did a little bit of experimenting and I still don't really get what's going on.  For example, given your suggestions I thought something like ``cmd /k echo off`` should also work (since ``/k`` should leave cmd.exe running after ``echo off``) but it doesn't.  Also, apparently powershell.exe doesn't have this command echoing property (according to various dubious posts online) but it exhibits the same behavior as a job from within Vim.